# OCR using Tensor flow,Python

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ocr

I'm new to Python and ML.I'm trying to get a simple code for character recognition  using tensor flow. A simple python code which searches whether the entered text is present in the uploaded file or not and prints the same.

Could someone help me on this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if you already have found answers by now.

I doubt anyone would like to give solutions straight away when there are no research details included. However, I could point you to some links which may be useful.

[Deep Learning OCR using TensorFlow and Python](https://nicholastsmith.wordpress.com/2017/10/14/deep-learning-ocr-using-tensorflow-and-python/)

Github Implementation: https://github.com/argman/EAST

However, if you are new to ML I would suggest you take it slow and start off with a learning path. I am no expert myself and learning using various sources online.